# git push origin in another remote branch by mistake

Tags: git, github

by mistake I pushed some commits using:

```
git push origin local_branch_name
```

but I was not in the main, I was actually in another different branch.
Is it possible to correct the mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: What _did_ you mean to do?

Comment: If you were in `local_branch_name` at the time, then what you did should be just fine. What's the "mistake" part?

Comment: I mean that before pushing to the origin I did not checkout in the main branch but I was still in another different branch, so now I have two branches with the commits mixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
git push origin foobranch
```

pushes any required new commits you have, that the Git over on `origin` lacks, and then asks the Git software on `origin` to set *their* branch named `foobranch` to point to the same commit that is the last commit (the *tip* commit, to use the Git terminology) of your branch `foobranch`.

It does not matter whether you are currently "on" branch `foobranch` locally: the effect of this `git push` command is to find new `foobranch` commits—commits you have, but `origin` does not have—and send those to `origin` and ask them to create-or-update *their* `foobranch`.

You added, in a comment, that:

> I mean that before pushing to the origin I did not checkout in the main branch but I was still in another different branch, so now I have two branches with the commits mixed

Had you run `git checkout main` or `git switch main` before your `git push origin foobranch` operation, *there would be no difference*.

Most Git commits are on multiple branches!  This is not an error.  A *branch name*, in Git, simply locates the *most recent* commit that we wish to say is "on" that branch.  All *earlier* commits [reachable from](https://think-like-a-git.net/) that last commit are also on that branch, even if they are also on some other branch.